# Using Viewsets to Encapsulate Related Endpoints

Tags: django-rest-framework

I like the way that Viewsets can use Routers and can keep several Endpoint together without having to Register each of them in urls.py separately.

I am implementing mappings to send to the UI to map short codes that are stored in our database to display names (from TextChoices). The set is going to keep growing..

```
from .models import AssetTypes, Countries, Exchanges


    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def asset_types(self, request, pk=None):
        """
        API endpoint that gets the mappings from the two character asset type id that is stored in the database and the
        text to be displayed.
        """
        return JsonResponse(choice_to_json('asset_type', AssetTypes))

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def exchanges(self, request, pk=None):
        """
        API endpoint that gets the mappings from the one character exchange id at is stored in the database and the
        text to be displayed.
        """
        return JsonResponse(choice_to_json('exchange', Exchanges))

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def countries(self, request, pk=None):
        """
        API endpoint that gets the mappings from the two character country id that is stored in the database and the
        text to be displayed.
        """
        return JsonResponse(choice_to_json('country', Countries))
```

The three return exactly what I want, but if the caller happens to just use the parent url, then there is an error due to the fact that I don't have a query_set or backing model for this.

```
/mapping/counrties # Works as expected
/mapping # No implementation so gets exception
```

Is there an appropriate way to implement this scenario using a ViewSet, or will I have to drop back to @api_view and registering every one separately?

Comment: for this you can use APIView.